# Is there a way to wrap background color around text in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Currently, this is what I am trying to avoid. As you can see the background color runs until the end of the width. It would be nice for the background color to surround the text.

[image]

I looked a tons of examples and I don't really see where they wrap background color around the text itself

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}> TTeexxtt </Text>
```

I tried with flexWrap and it doesn't work just like so

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor:'blue', flexWrap:'wrap'}}> TTeexxtt </Text>
```

As always, thank you

Comment: can you describe what you mean by "wrap background color around text"? Are you just wanting some extra space around the text where the background color is? that would just be some `padding`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've updated the question with an image and comments for what I am looking for.

Comment: Have your tried `display` property like `inline` or `inline-block`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: two text lines with different sized pink and orange backgrounds behind them]

Views in react native default to an `alignItems` prop of stretch. What does this mean though?

All children of your view will stretch to fill the width of their parent, with considerations for margin.

If you set the `alignItems` property of your parent view to something other than `stretch`, such as `center`, `flex-start`, or `flex-end` you will see the background color only extend around your actual text.

You can also use `alignSelf` on your Text views to adjust individual items.

Here is an example snack 
https://snack.expo.io/@ajthyng/vengeful-celery

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const BGText = props => {
  const { background } = props;
  return <Text style={{backgroundColor: background, ...props.style}}>{props.children}</Text>;
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'stretch', marginTop: 23}}>
        <BGText background='pink' style={{marginRight: 16}}>I am some text</BGText>
        <BGText background='orange' style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 16}} >My BG Color is short</BGText>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```